# Removing redundant color box in VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

New to coding.
How do I remove the redundant color box next to the highlighted(colored) item in VSCode?
I like to keep 'Colorize' and remove the unknown and redundant extension.

Here are the extensions I have installed.
[image: Enabled Extensions Screenshot]

Here is the issue screenshot.
[image: code screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

As of VS Code v1.49 (August 2020), this is the setting:

```
"editor.colorDecorators": false
```

Comment: Thank you. This hides both boxes though. How can configure my settings so that it still shows one?

Answer (score 4):

Add this lines in your settings.json by pressing ctrl+shift+p and pressing Open Settings (JSON)

```
"css.colorDecorators.enable": false,
"scss.colorDecorators.enable": false,
"less.colorDecorators.enable": false,
```