# What are these color boxes in typescript file in my VScode and how to remove these?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just want to get rid of these boxes, my ts file is full of these boxes.

[image]

I have tried many settings in vs code but not get success, so if anyone have any answer please help me

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786584/removing-redundant-color-box-in-vs-code) might help you. These boxes are for you to see the colours you've written in the code.

Comment: no, I don't think so, coz on hover these boxes it shows method complexity
plus these are in typescript file, and I don't use any color in my typescript file

Comment: use the extension bisect to determine which extension generates these `complexity` values